# how to push multiple values to same hash key

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, hash

a beginner question here, please help me out

```
my_array = ["city1:state1","city2:state2","city3:state1","city4:state3","city5:state1"]
```

from this array how can i make a hash like this?

```
{
 state1: [city1,city3,city5],
 state2: [city2],
 state3: [city4]
}
```

i am trying this way

```
my_hash = { }
my_array.each do |cs|
 temp = cs.split(":")
 if my_hash.keys.include? temp[1]
  my_hash[temp[1]] = temp[0]
 else
  my_hash[temp[1]] = temp[0]
 end
end
```

but i am not getting how to match keys of my hash and append to keys.

Comment: Question is not clear. What is the logic behind the value for `:state3` being `[city3]`? What are the values of `city1`, `city2`, `city3`, and `city5`?

Comment: Have you mistyped the value of `state3:[city3]` instead of `state3:[city4]`?

Comment: @Surya yes thats typing mistake

Comment: @sawa Sorry, i thought u'll understand the prototype.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little modification can work:

```
my_hash = { }
my_array.each do |cs|
 temp = cs.split(":")
 if my_hash.keys.include? temp[1].to_sym
  my_hash[temp[1].to_sym] << temp[0]
 else
  my_hash[temp[1].to_sym] = [temp[0]]
 end
end
```

Result is `{:state1=>["city1", "city3", "city5"], :state2=>["city2"], :state3=>["city4"]}`. I'm assuming this is what you mean (the keys are symbols, and the values are arrays of strings).

Answer (score 1):

Try this(considering that you mistyped `state3:[city3]` instead of `state3:[city4]` in your question):

```
my_array = ["city1:state1","city2:state2","city3:state1","city4:state3","city5:state1"]

my_hash = { }

my_array.each do |cs|
  value, key = cs.split(":")
  key = key.to_sym
  if my_hash[key].present?
    my_hash[key] << value
  else
    my_hash[key] = [value]
  end
end

my_hash #=> {:state1=>["city1", "city3", "city5"], :state2=>["city2"], :state3=>["city4"]}
```

Or, one-liner:

```
my_hash = my_array.inject({}){|h, cs| value, key = cs.split(":"); key = key.to_sym; h[key].present? ? (h[key] << value) : h[key] = [value]; h }
my_hash #=> {:state1=>["city1", "city3", "city5"], :state2=>["city2"], :state3=>["city4"]}
```

or even better(based on jesper's idea of Hash):

```
my_array.inject(Hash.new{|h,k| h[k] = [] }){ |my_hash, cs| value, key = cs.split(":"); my_hash[key.to_sym] << value; my_hash }
my_hash #=> {:state1=>["city1", "city3", "city5"], :state2=>["city2"], :state3=>["city4"]}
```

Comment: That does not give the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Hash defaults to achieve an alternative solution:

```
my_array = ["city1:state1","city2:state2","city3:state1","city4:state3","city5:state1"]

hash = Hash.new do |hash, key| 
  hash[key] = []
end

my_array.each_with_object(hash) do |string, hash|
  city, state = string.split(":")
  hash[state.to_sym] << city
end
# => {:state1=>["city1", "city3", "city5"], :state2=>["city2"], :state3=>["city4"]}
```